# Receive partial file(sometimes) when reading from Google Storage using HTTP Response

Tags: httpresponse, google-api-java-client, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to read files from Google Storage and write it to files in our filesystem (HDFS). If i run it for a period of time (lets say 7 days), sometimes i get the full file with lines matching with whats on the source and sometimes i get partial files (discrepancy is quite large). I am pasting below the method that takes a response and writes it to a file. 
Any help or suggestions as to how i can troubleshoot this further would be much appreciated.

### Thanks,

Before calling this method i do a simple check on the response status code -

```
if(response.getStatusCode() == 200 &&
                    StringUtils.equals(response.getContentType(), "application/zip")) {
                    writeHdfsFile(response, path);
}

private void writeHdfsFile(HttpResponse response, String path) throws IOException {
        final GZIPInputStream inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(response.getContent());
        Path filePath = new Path(path);
        final FSDataOutputStream outputStream = fileSystem.create(filePath, true);
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        try {
            while((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we solved it was downloading the file first and then unzipping and writing it. Basically, splitting it into two steps solved that issue. If someone else ran into the same issue..